# Reallife example multiscreen with three.js for large virtual display

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, multiscreen

The new examples for multiscreen purpose that you can see here :

[webgl_multiple_canvases_circle](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_canvases_circle)

[webgl_multiple_canvases_complex](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_canvases_complex)

[webgl_multiple_canvases_grid](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_canvases_grid)

Are really cool, they even talk about the google Liquid galaxy project : [liquidGalaxy](http://www.google.com/earth/explore/showcase/liquidgalaxy.html)

So, basically, I wonder how would I adapt the app in order to fit the need of multiple screen, lets say four 1920x1080 display, all displaying a nice part of the image.

I end up with a basic proof of concept, where I simply display new window screen content/canvas and sync the mouse position thru a node.js server and socket.io.

This works smoothly until I display window of different size.

See bellow the case where it fails.

For the record, please note that the full app is not working (the screen are not yet ready to be created on different computer), I'd like to first fix this offset issue.

thanks !

Oh, and if you want to try out or contribute, the project is here :

[Screeny](https://github.com/soixantecircuits/screeny)

[image: Here, you can see the scene is a bit distorded and the window height are different]

[image: Here, you can see the scene is a ok and the window height are the same]

Thanks again !

Comment: Can you modify the three.js complex example to put canvases of different heights on one machine? That seems to show it works. Here's an example: http://greggman.com/downloads/examples/three.js/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_complex_different_heights.html

Comment: Are you doing something special ? The image here : [Image with border](http://i.imgur.com/KCkP3pE.png) shows the border moving as the camera view change vertically ?
Also, did you tried the project with synched camera axis by socket.io ?

Comment: Ok got it :) you examples makes me think twice. As all the examples are based on one window only, I can not use the windowHalfX and windowHalfY value. Working on it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was quiet logical, the windowHalfX value should be passed to each window. Now it works perfectly and code is updated. thanks for your remark !

The solution was to transfered with the mouseMove event the size of the current window and accordingly update all the window based on the window where movement happen.

Going deeper to make a fully working examples for separated computer.

Comment: If it was me I'd transfer the camera's info (translation, rotation, fov), not the mouse movements.

Comment: well, depend on the final use, I'm just trying to check that the multiscreen / area rendering could be use in real life. So basically, you are right, for non interactive and for simple Scene rendering camera position synching would be the best.
I'll keep you posted when the configurator will be ready.